# redirect_uri_mismatch error when using OAuth Google Client program

Tags: java, google-maps, oauth-2.0, google-fusion-tables, google-api-java-client

I am using the google OAuth java client to get my application authourized by google for accessing google fusion table data.
I used the code at here http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/fusiontables-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/fusiontables/cmdline/FusionTablesSample.java?repo=samples

I am using a servlet which uses the above sample code, i am using Service Account mode to get authorized from google server.
While i am using the above code i am getting the following error.

**Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request: [http://localhost:51034/Callback] did not match a registered redirect URI**

I see that when we create Client Id and Secret for Service Accounts there is no redirections URIs mentioned. So where can i change or edit these uris to make this code work.

Present my code is at this url.
http://rajeshtestapi.blogspot.in/2013/01/sample-code.html

Answer (score 2):

You can edit these settings in the [API console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) (in the *API Access* section), at the same place where you can add Service Accounts. Just use "Edit settings..." and there you can add JavaScript redirects and origins:

[image: Client settings]

Answer (score 2):

Using Java code in a servlet to access google OAuth2 is called "web application" or "web server" type. 
When you create ClientID in API Console, choose "Web application", and then you can edit its redirect_uris using what @Odi 's screenshot shows.